# SNMPv3 Failed authentification warnings (traps)

Tags: snmp, cisco-ios-xr

Is't someshow possible to enable SNMPv3 failed/wrong authentification events to be sent to some logging server or just the log message to be triggered on device itself ?

I talking about IOSXR/IOS/IOS-XE and NX-OS devices.

edit:

The IOS-XE/IOS models would be: CISCO ISR 44xx, and Cisco WS-C2960+48TC-S.

The Cisco ISR 44xx configuration is here from (show running-configuration full)

```
logging history informational
logging snmp-trap emergencies
logging snmp-trap alerts
logging snmp-trap critical
logging snmp-trap errors
logging snmp-trap warnings
logging snmp-trap informational
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkdown linkup coldstart warmstart
```

Comment: Have you enabled `logging trap notifications` and `snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication`?

Comment: on nexus i see only [snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication] , but not [logging trap notifications]. After I enable only [snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication?]. And doing some incorrect authentiifiations - i dont see any alerts present..

Comment: Try to enable log level for SNMP `logging level snmpd 6`

Comment: Please post your configuration, so that i can check if you need something. It works fine on my Nexus 6000.

Comment: thanks Crown, on NX-OS it's working. Any idea howto do it on IOSXR and IOS-XE ? Thanks!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have configured SNMPv3 correctly with group/user/views etc.

For IOS/IOS-XE (Sorry don't have any IOS XR available)

```
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication
logging trap informational
logging history informational
logging snmp-trap informational
```

NX-OS on Nexus platforms etc.

```
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication
logging level snmpd 6
```

Comment: thank you, seems that commands on IOS-XE doesnt work fully, i enter them but no log on output..

Comment: @saddayz that is very strange. Try `logging snmp-trap informational` on IOS XE. You can use the same command on IOS it seems...

Comment: tried it on IOS-XE and IOS. But no output is comming. Maybe something is left ?

Comment: @saddayz for the sake of troubleshooting, try to enable all traps with `snmp-server enable traps` and see if it does anything. I don't understand as it works on my switches.

Comment: tahnks, did it, no message on "show logging" any more ideas ? :)

Comment: @saddayz could you update your post with the switch model and configuration?

Comment: did it: edit: 

The IOS-XE/IOS models would be: CISCO ISR 44xx, and Cisco WS-C2960+48TC-S.

Comment: @saddayz and the current configuration?

Comment: thanks, i added the configuration to the main post from show running configuration

Answer (score 0):

the command `debug snmp config` enables snmp debug messages on the cli. 
 You can also use the `debug snmp packets` command to look at all incoming and outgoing snmp packets on the cli. It is recommended to limit the output of this debug command by applying it over an acl, this can be done by adding the `detail <acl-name or acl-number>`. I can see that you've enabled logging for levels 0-6 but left out the debugging(level 7). Make sure to enable snmp-trap debugging and logging for the same.

Comment: thank you, debug snmp config doesnt work. Debug snmp packets drops this message "%IOSXE_INFRA-3-CONSOLE_DBUG_DROP: System dropped 204 bytes of console debug messages."

Comment: This means that the console can't handle the message length,i recommend logging it in a buffer. An example of this is,
`logging buffered <buffer size in bytes(example 10000000 - for 10 mb)>`
`no logging console`
`no logging monitor`
`logging trap debugging`
`logging host <syslog server ip>`
The `logging trap debugging` command is needed only if logging to a syslog server is required.

Comment: hello. Thanks, can you help me with the combination of commands to enable the SNMPv3 Failed authentification warnings onto the 'show loggs' output ?